# How to strip newline in string from readline() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

For some reason the code won't increase the score when a correct answer is entered. It is a multiple choice quiz and so that is why it asks for entry of the correct letter for the answer. I have checked and there is nothing wrong with the answer or userAnswer variables but even when they both match, the score value doesn't increase by 1. MathQuiz.txt is a file that contains my questions and answers for the quiz. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.
This is my code:

```
def questions():
    lol = open("MathQuiz.txt", 'r')
    score = 0

    for x in range(5):
        print(lol.readline())
        print(lol.readline())
        answer = lol.readline()
        userAnswer = input("Please chooose the letter correponding to your answer: ")
        while userAnswer.isspace() or userAnswer == "":
            print("You must enter a valid letter.")
            userAnswer = input("Please chooose the letter correponding to your answer: ")
        if answer == userAnswer:
            score += 1 
        else:
            score = score
        print(lol.readline())

    print("Your score is ", score)

questions()
```

The text file looks like this:

1.What is my name?

a)Grace      b)Ellie     c)Craig     d)Veronica

d

2.What is my age?

a)12         b)18        c)45        d)15

a

3.Where do I live?

a)Birmingham     b)London    c)Leeds     d)Scotland

c

4.What is my birthday?

a)6th May        b)4th Jan       c)12th August       d)12th June

d

5.What is my favourite colour?

a)orange     b)Red       c)Blue      d)Pink

c

[These answers are not correct - it's a random example]

Comment: Have you looked at the representation of each?

Comment: Can you try this before comparing? answer = lol.readline().strip(). I think the new line character is throwing you off

Comment: @rgk It works. Thank you so much I've been stuck on this for days

Comment: Obviously they don't, or that wouldn't have fixed it.

Comment: Why `score = score`?

Comment: @AndrewGillis just to ensure that the score value stays the same if the wrong answer is given. Is it not necessary?

Comment: Why are you calling readline() multiple times?

Comment: @ElisByberi I'm going to take a guess that one line is the question, the next is the possible options and the next is the answer/correct option... It'd help to confirm if the OP showed a sample of their input file though.

Comment: @ElisByberi  Jon Clements is right. I've added an example of the layout of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone needing the answer to this, @rgk has let me know that

```
answer = lol.readline().strip()
```

is how to solve my problem :)